# DC Analysis of CMOS-inverter

Tags: inverter, cmos, transfer-function

I am studying about CMOS inverter and in my book provided the transfer characteristic as follows (actually i simulated it):
[image]

and then I changed the parameters and I got something like this:
[image]

I found later case interesting because it got two flat regions on curve.

Now in the first case I entered the \$V_{T_{N}}=1 V\$ , \$V_{T_{P}}=-1 V\$ and in second case \$V_{T_{N}}=3 V\$ , \$V_{T_{P}}=-3 V\$. In the first case there is only one region where gain is huge in between about \$1.5V\$ to \$2.5V\$ but in second case there are two such regions one is at \$1.3V\$ and another is just after \$3V\$. I am curious to know what causing this kind of behavior?

Comment: You should try with some kind of load connected to the output. Say 50 kohms to either Vdd or ground (try both and see if you can explain the results).

Comment: Also it would be helpful to see your schematic (no matter how simple). If this is a SPICE or similar simulation, also include the back-gate connections.

Comment: Think about what happens in the case that Vt = 3 V and Vin = 2.5 V. Both transistors would be off. Or are they ? What happes when Vgs , Vt ? Weak inversion perhaps ? So what will then determine the voltage at the output ?

Comment: Here's my simulation http://tinyurl.com/gmomfmm